# Методы then и catch промисов в JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

товарищи!
Начал осваивать промисы. Есть вопросы к нюансам.

Есть задача: Записать строку `text` в файл `pathFile1`, считать данные из него, посчитать количество слов, полученный результат записать в файл `pathFile2`, удалить файл `pathFile2`.

Имеется такой код:

```
writeFileAsync(pathFile1, text)
  .then(() => readFileAsync(pathFile1))
  .then(data => data.split(' ').length) //????????
  .then(countOfWords => writeFileAsync(pathFile2, `Количество слов: ${String(countOfWords)}`))
  .then(() => removeFileAsync(pathFile1))
  .catch(err => console.log('Ошибка: ' + err));
```

Функции `readFileAsync()`, `writeFileAsync()` и `removeFileAsync()` выглядят примерно так:

```
const readFileAsync = async (path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Код работает как надо, но есть вопрос. Написанные мной асинхронные функции возвращают промис, и я понимаю, что в then() приходит позитивный результат промиса. Информацию брал [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-basics#comments). Однако меня смущает связь 2-го и 3-го then() в цепочке. Я наткнулся на информацию, что then() и catch() всегда возвращают промис, но не понимаю, почему 3-й then() считает, что предыдущий промис завершился успешно? Ведь напрямую мы не используем функцию, в которой были бы указаны `resolve` и `reject`. В данном случае имееем просто код, разбивающий массив на элементы.

По-моему, если написать таким образом:

```
.catch(countOfWords => writeFileAsync(pathFile2, `Количество слов: ${String(countOfWords)}`))
```

то данный код также должен выполниться, поскольку `countOfWords` может быть возвращаемой ошибкой. Почему нет?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вас смущает тот факт, что `data.split(' ').length` не является промисом? В [следующей главе](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-chaining) по вашей ссылке на это есть ответ: «Когда обработчик возвращает какое-то значение, то оно **становится результатом выполнения** соответствующего промиса и передаётся в следующий `.then`»

Comment: Ответ был близко . Спасибо!